# If V is an inner product space, prove that for all x,y in V

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

1/4 { $||x + y||^2$  - $||x - y||^2$} = $<x,y>$

Ok at first i really had no idea how to start this but i spend about 5 minutes trying to do this and this is what i came up with..

1) i multiplied both sides by 4 to get rid of the fraction..

$||x + y||^2$  - $||x - y||^2$ = 4$<x,y>$

2) I know that $<x,y>$ is just the dot product and will give a scalar, which we define as $\lambda$

$||x + y||^2$  - $||x - y||^2$ = 4 $\lambda$

3) the magnitude of x+y and x-y will give the squareroot of a scalar, the squareroot will cancel itself with the exponent, we will represent the result of this with n and m

n - m = 4 $\lambda$

this is as far as i can go by myself. If i tried going any further, i will only stare at my paper for hours

any help will be appreciated

Comment: For the record, the inner product is only called the dot product when working in a real inner product space equipped with either the standard inner product, or when working out of an orthonormal basis

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

$$||x + y||^2=<x+y,x+y>=||x||^2+2<x,y>+||y||^2$$

$$||x - y||^2=<x-y,x-y>=|x||^2-2<x,y>+||y||^2$$

Comment: Are we to assume this is a real inner product space? As your right equality fails to hold if the field is $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: $||x+y||^2$= $<x+y,x+y>$ =  $(x + y)^2$ = $x^2$ + 2xy + $y^2$ this is what i got so far.. i dont understand why you changed $x^2$ to $||x||^2$ and $y^2$ to $||y||^2$ can you elaborate on this please

Comment: Nevermind, i figured it out, thank you so much!

Comment: Yes I’ve assumed the ordinary inner product on reals.

Answer (score 0):

Use this and FOIL.

$$\|x + y\|^2 = \langle x + y, x + y\rangle.$$